# Live search with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im trying to make a search function that filters out the locations based on the title. But I cant seem to figure out how to get the title in the location array. Ive tried location.title and that comes back as undefined.

```
 var locationArray = [
  {title:'State House', location:{lat: 41.763711, lng:-72.685093} },
  {title:'Hartford School', location:{lat: 41.755042, lng:-72.665532} },
  {title:'BurgerKing', location:{lat: 41.757419, lng:-72.664175} },
  {title:'Subway', location:{lat: 41.767228, lng:-72.676470} },
  {title:'Quiznos', location:{lat: 41.764117, lng:-72.671873} }
  ];



 var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.filter = ko.observable('');

  self.items = ko.observableArray(locationArray);
  console.log(locationArray);

  self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = self.filter();
    if (!filter) { return self.items(); }
    return self.items().filter(function(i) { return i.indexOf(filter) > -1; });
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

here is my js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/0qy8qmgm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, please check this updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0qy8qmgm/1/

I only change

```
return self.items().filter(function(i) { return i.indexOf(filter) > -1; });
```

for this

```
return self.items().filter(function(i) { return i.title.indexOf(filter) > -1; });
```